# Gridstack, is there a way to get the blocks sort order?

Tags: jquery, gridstack

I'm using gridstack to build a layout visual editor, I've realized a script to add widgets to the working area. My aim is to get the DOM's HTML content and paste it on a textarea. The script is working fine, but I don't need to know the exact position of each div as on JSON, instead, I need to know their sort order.
The problem is that even if I'm changing each div position on the screen, their DOM position has always the same order.
Any idea?